# In select tag values passing as value="<ul id=" id_process" in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Using `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget in the forms, The `select` tag `value` attribute is automatically not generating properly the `Inspect(F12)` code is given below

```
<select name="process" required="" class="valid">
     <option value="<ul id=" id_process"></option>
</select>
```

How can I pass id in the `value` attribute

**forms.py**

```
class Client_ProcessForm(forms.Form):
    process = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset= Process.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

**views.py**

```
def Add_Client(request):
    form = Client_ProcessForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        cname = request.POST['cname']
        print(cname)
        process = request.POST.getlist('process')
        print(process)
        obj = Client(Name=cname)
        obj.save()
        for i in range(1, len(process)):
            cp_obj = Client_Process.objects.bulk_create([
                Client_Process(client = Client.objects.get(Name=cname),
                process = Process.objects.get(id=process[i]))
            ])
    return render(request, 'add_client.html',{'form': form})
```

html

```
<div>
          <label>Process:</label><br>
            <select name="process" required>
              {% for entry in form %}
              <option value="{{ entry }}"> {{ entry.process }} </option> {% endfor %} </select> </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You need to show the form, view and template.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I have added my forms, view and html file, plz refer above